# geckodriver download location other than github?

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver, selenium3

It might sound strange but Github.com is blocked in my organization and I need to download geckodriver.exe file.

I tried finding alternative places for the file download, but it all ended up pointing to Github location.

Does anyone know any other place from where I can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the GitHub repository using a [Web Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy_servers). Here are some free options:

- https://hide.me/pt/proxy
- https://www.hidemyass.com/pt/proxy
- https://whoer.net/webproxy

You can also bypass most firewalls by browsing with [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/).

Comment: Access to (all 3 of these) proxy locations is also _restricted_!

Comment: Just added a link to Tor (which is probably also blocked).

Comment: You guessed it right. I need to get it through a legit location other than GitHub.

Comment: Smartphone + Data Plan + E-mail is always an option!